# Getting DependencyResolutionException in azure app only When Date changes ,works fine with fresh new Deployment

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am getting a weird problem. When deploying my application to azure everything works fine but when date changes application throws `DependencyResolutionException` restarted the App but nothing is working.

`ConfigCache` is not a cache, it is used to get the configurations stored in DB in place of getting the values from web.config

All the other services are getting resolved

```
builder.Register(c => new SMSService(c.Resolve<myContext>(), 
                                     c.Resolve<ILogger>(), 
                                     c.Resolve<IConfigCache>()))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

[image]

Comment: The exception related to the SMSService. Which SMS provider or library did you use? Please check whether the authentication token which you provided for SMS library is out of date. In addition, is this issue happened on your environment? I suggest you deploy your web application to local environment and check whether it is a issue from azure web app service.

Comment: SMSService is a normal service which I am using to send Email and OTP , not using any library.

Comment: Some files in your application maybe changed or deleted after dated changed. I suggest you view the detail files information order by [Date Modified] using FTP to view the last modified file and check why this file has been modified.